# .Net Core StringBuilder encoding on Mac

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, pinvoke

I have a following C function:

```
LIBRARY_API HRESULT LA_CC GetRSAKeyPair(STRTYPE privateKeyPtr, STRTYPE publicKeyPtr)
{
    int length = 2048;
    string privateKey, publicKey;
    if (GenerateRSAKeyPair(privateKey, publicKey) == false)
    {
        return FAIL;
    }
#ifndef _WIN32
        *privateKeyPtr = '\0'; // assumes `dest_size > 0`
        strncat(privateKeyPtr, privateKey.c_str(), length);
        *publicKeyPtr = '\0'; // assumes `dest_size > 0`
        strncat(publicKeyPtr, publicKey.c_str(), length);
#else
        *privateKeyPtr = L'\0'; // assumes `dest_size > 0`
        wcsncat(privateKeyPtr, toUTF16(privateKey).c_str(), length);
        *publicKeyPtr = L'\0'; // assumes `dest_size > 0`
        wcsncat(publicKeyPtr, toUTF16(publicKey).c_str(), length);
#endif
    return OK;
}
```

It is invoked using pinvoke:

```
[DllImport(DLL_FILE_NAME, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern int GetRSAKeyPair(StringBuilder privateKey, StringBuilder publicKey);
```

And when used:

```
StringBuilder privateKey = new StringBuilder(2048);
StringBuilder publicKey = new StringBuilder(2048);
LibraryNative.GetRSAKeyPair(privateKey, publicKey);
Console.WriteLine(privateKey);
Console.WriteLine(publicKey);
```

The output returns data in chinese, though same code works fine on Windows. The native library assumes encoding is not utf-16 on non-windows platform, but seems like stringbuilder expects utf-16 on nix too.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm toUTF16() won't be invoked on mac and linux, it actually converts string to wstring.

Comment: Seems like the code does exactly what it says. Utf16 on Windows, 8 bit elsewhere. So the behaviour you observe is to be expected. You receive an 8 bit string but interpret it as UTF16. What do you think CharSet = CharSet.Unicode means?  Why are you surprised. Also, it's C++ and not C.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On mac i am not converting it to utf16, the native code assumes it to be 8bit string, but stringbuilder is treating it as utf16, how do i fix it?

Comment: Read my comment again. Especially the part about CharSet. As for how to fix it, who knows. We'd need to know what this 8 bit encoding is. Not clear from here. We're it me though, I'd be wanting to use consistent encoding. Having a function that yields an 8 bit encoding on what platform and a 16 bit encoding on another platform is, in view, terrible design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation  can be found in the conditional code in your C++. Here you opt to use an 8 bit encoding on platforms other than Windows, but use UTF16 on Windows. The C# code, on the other hand, explicitly states that the text is UTF16 encoding, through the use of `CharSet.Unicode`. .

This mismatch explains the behaviour you observe. How to fix it? Well, you need to make sure that both sides of the interface, managed and unmanaged, use the same encoding.

Your current strategy of a different encoding for different platforms seem to be asking for trouble to me. That will just lead to confusion. My advice is to pick a single encoding for interop. For instance UTF16 would be a sound choice that makes the interop simplest because the pinvoke marshaler understands it natively.

Comment: Windows uses utf-16 for unicode whereas Linux defaults to utf-8, the above code was written keeping that in mind, the std::string class actually meaning utf-8, I thought .NetCore will use utf-8 for unicode on mac/linux

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller uses the encoding you specified, `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`, as I think I stated in the answer. There is no `CharSet.UTF8` so you are best using `CharSet.UTF16` everywhere in my opinion. By the way, what encoding does your C++ code use on Windows. UTF-8 or ANSI? If the latter then you probably have other problems.

Comment: If you don't want to use UTF-16 everywhere, then you might opt for UTF-8 everywhere. But that in turn makes the marshalling harder. There is no `CharSet.UTF8`. So you'd need to marshal into a byte array and use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to decode into a native .net string.

Comment: On Windows the library uses wchar_t and wstring and all the input strings are wchat_t *, for Linux and Mac it uses char* and string internally and same for all the inputs, since the output string is supposedly ascii base64 encoded key in this particular case, i think using CharSet.Ansi should work, but i am stuck for cases where output string can have codepoints other than ascii. Definitely a bad decision to support different unicode encodings:(